# When I am appending a NSString with another NSstring it Gives me an error "EXC BAD ACCESS"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Solved....Check at bottom of Body..

I am using XCODE 4

I have an Money Calculator Application in which I have to press the digit buttons and I have to see it on the TextLabel.

Format like : "$ 500"

So for $ I am appending it..

The method works twice well but the third time it crashes..

Rest if you see the code you will have an Idea.

In my Application I have Three String variables...

-(void)viewDidLoad
{

```
  current =[[NSString alloc] retain];

  current=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Total"]];



  NSString *newCurrent=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %@",current];

  textViewer.text=newCurrent;

 NSLog(@"%@",current);
```

}

-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender {

```
NSString *str= (NSString* )[sender currentTitle];

//NSLog(@"1 The Value Of String %@",str);

NSLog(@"Befor Appending %@",current);


if([current isEqualToString:@"0"])
{
    current =  str;
}
else 
{

   current = [current stringByAppendingString:str];

    NSLog(@"After Appending %@",current);

}


NSString *newCurrent=@"$ ";

newCurrent = [newCurrent stringByAppendingString:current];

textViewer.text= newCurrent;
```

}
Error is 1st time it is working fine but

> when I call it second time, current is Pointing to some Standard Time
>   formatted value, some time it points to some file name value,

Error is: EXC BAD ACCESS
**When I am doing it without newCurrent means without appending a letter it works fine.**

-------SOLVED----------------
Every thing is Ok with My Code I just have to right **[current retain];** where ever I am appending the String to the current.

As I was receiving the error EXC BAD ACCESS means I was referring to the Object which was released previously.
So, I have retained the Object instead.

Comment: try nslogging all the variables when you hit it third time. lemme know the value of current and currentTitle at the time of the crash.

Comment: Actually Sir, I have done NSLogs, At the start of the method 1 st time Value is Before Appending "96",After Appending "961" (As I have pressed 1 in UI. Second time when the method called Current value before appending ..Actually whenever it encounters current at this time exc bad access..so I cant see the nslog second time...,hopes some solution u suggest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code (without memory leaks):

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    current=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"20"];
}

-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *str= (NSString* )[sender currentTitle];

    NSString *nCurrent = [current stringByAppendingString:str];
    [current release];
    current = [nCurrent retain];

   NSString *newCurrent=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"a%@", current];
   textViewer.text= newCurrent;
   [newCurrent release];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
     [current release];
     [super dealloc];   
}
```

Comment: This is just going to leak memory repeatedly.

Comment: In this question memory management is not goal. After removing current problem he could make memory management. We see only part of code...

Comment: You're leaking memory with the NSString *newCurrent=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"a"];newCurrent=[newCurrent stringByAppendingString:current]; lines and it will crash when you over release newCurrent

Comment: I can not release the current As I need it to compare it with next method call....

Comment: And it will be there, as I assign new value in line `current = [nCurrent retain];`!

Answer (score 0):

no need to alloc or retain the string in both the cases.

**in viewdidload**
s = [[NSString alloc] init];
    s = @"a";

**in button click**

```
NSString *newStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"b"];
s = [s stringByAppendingString:newStr];
NSLog(@"s is :%@",s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Arpit,

You can declare property of nsstring in .h file and synthesize it in .m file so i think its help you.

.h file

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) 
NSString *current;
```

.m file

```
@synthesize current;
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a lot of issues here.

1. you have a memory leak in your viewDidLoad when you set current = to a newly allocated object then replace it with @"20"; you've now lost your pointer to the allocated memory. the correct way to do this would be simply to remove the alloc line.
2. you have another memory leak when you set newCurrent = [newCurrent stringByAppendingString:current]; for the same reason as 1.

You either need to manage your memory better or just use NSMutableStrings. Change current to be a NSMutableString alloc/init it in your init or viewDidLoad and then just use `[current appendString:str];`

based on your code you pasted I'd do the following.

in your @interface declare a property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *current;
```

in your @implementation @synthesize it

```
@synthesize current; 

- (void) viewdidload
{
    self.current = @"20";
}

-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *str= (NSString* )[sender currentTitle];
    self.current = [self.current stringByAppendingString:str];

    NSString *newCurrent = @"a";
    newCurrent = [newCurrent stringByAppendingString:self.current];

    textViewer.text = newCurrent;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? Just adding retains to your code isn't fixing it.